# Java - Renaming Enum constants

Tags: java, enums, constants

I'm trying to make it so I can edit enum constants' names.

I have these classes:

```
public class MasterClass implements Serializable {


/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7117733089486585811L;
private Sex sex;

public Sex getSex(){
    return sex;
}


}
```

.

```
public class Sex implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -4688254148082455942L;


private EnumModel model;

public String print(){
    return model.name();
}

public static String print(String n){
    return EnumModel.byName(n).name();
}

private static enum EnumModel {

    MALE_1(1, 2, 3),

    MALE_2(1, 2, 3),

    FEMALE_1(1, 2, 3),

    FEMALE_2(1, 2, 3)

    ;
    private int x, y, z;
    EnumModel(int...is){
        x = is[0];
        y = is[1];
        z = is[2];
    }

    public static EnumModel byName(String n){
        for (EnumModel a : EnumModel.values()){
            if (n.toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ", "_").equalsIgnoreCase(a.name().toLowerCase()))
                return a;

        }
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

Then after when I edit the name of the enum constant, for example, if I were to rename MALE_1 to MALE_ONE, then I will get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.masterclass.sex.Sex.EnumModel.MALE_1
at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readEnum(ObjectInputStream.java:1750)
```

Because MALE_1 obviously no longer exists, the only way I can fix this is to delete the saved MasterClass and creating a new one.

How do I re-name constants without this issue?

Comment: Use your IDE to rename it and it will update all usages too.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to read serialized data. This won't work if the Class/Enum doesn't match anymore with the serialized data.

Comment: I use Eclipse's refractor tool and it gives the same error

Comment: OP, you say that you're attempting to change an enum constant but haven't posted any code that reflects that, so I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Just don’t rename them, if you want to have a maintainable persistent storage. It’s the same as renaming classes or instance variables. Persistence and refactoring are not good friends.

Answer (score 0):

Update serialVersionUid of the Sex class when you change it and write a custom deserializer (readObject) which checks versions and deserializes as appropriate. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javaserial-1536170.html

Comment: Is this really the best option? It seems kind of excessive

Comment: You can do anything you want. If you only want to cover renaming you can serialize the enum as an int.